# How to get the average of each rows which include missing numbers?

Tags: r, matrix, mean

I have the following matrix - `example`:

```
        col1      col2      col3
S01LA   "0.0143"  "0.1286"  "---"                          
N01AX "0.0088"    "---"     "0.343"                         
N05AG "0.0927"    "0.8692"  "---"
```

And I want to get the average of each row. I tried doing this by changing the "---" values to `NA` and then using `colSums`

```
example[example=='---'] <- NA
row_means <- rowMeans(as.numeric(example), na.rm=TRUE)
```

which gives me the error

```
Error in colSums(as.numeric(copy_specificity_df), na.rm = TRUE) : 
   'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Because `as.numeric` flattens the dataframe. How can I get the average of all the rows in a dataframe, ignoring elements that can not be converted to floats?

Comment: I'm confused – Do you want the average (as stated in question title), or the sum (as indicated by your code via `colSums`)? Also, do you want the sum/average across the rows within each column (`colSums` or `colMeans`), or across columns within each row (`rowSums` or `rowMeans`)?

Comment: -1 If you had provided reproducible data, we would have all known that you have a matrix and not a data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of your "example" object and the attempts you've made indicate to me that even though you are calling your object a `data.frame`, it's actually a `matrix`.

My hints that you're actually using a `matrix`?

1. `data.frame`s don't generally print the quotes around strings.
2. `as.numeric(some_data_frame)` will give you an error about coercing a `list` to double.

With that, here's some example data:

```
example <- structure(c("0.0143", "0.0088", "0.0927", "0.1286", 
                 "---", "0.8692", "---", "0.343", "---"), 
               .Dim = c(3L, 3L), 
               .Dimnames = list(c("S01LA", "N01AX", "N05AG"), 
                                c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
example
#       col1     col2     col3   
# S01LA "0.0143" "0.1286" "---"  
# N01AX "0.0088" "---"    "0.343"
# N05AG "0.0927" "0.8692" "---"
```

Here's an approach you can take if that's the case.

```
example[example == "---"] <- NA   ## Replace "---" with `NA`
N <- as.numeric(example)          ## Convert to numeric. You can start here
dim(N) <- dim(example)            ## Restore the dimensions
dimnames(N) <- dimnames(example)  ## Restore the dimnames
colMeans(N, na.rm=TRUE)           ## Perform your calculation
#   col1   col2   col3 
# 0.0386 0.4989 0.3430
```

Note: You can actually skip the first line, but you'll get a `warning`.

Comment: `colSums`... `rowMeans`... `colMeans`... `rowSums`... have your pick :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know beforehand what the `NA` values look like in the raw data, you can use `na.strings` in `read.table`.  This effectively reads your data as three numeric columns. Make friends with the `args`.

```
> dat <- read.table(text = 'col1      col2      col3
  S01LA   "0.0143"  "0.1286"  "---"                          
  N01AX "0.0088"    "---"     "0.343"                         
  N05AG "0.0927"    "0.8692"  "---"', na.strings = "---")
> dat
#         col1   col2  col3
# S01LA 0.0143 0.1286    NA
# N01AX 0.0088     NA 0.343
# N05AG 0.0927 0.8692    NA
> colSums(dat, na.rm = TRUE)
##   col1   col2   col3 
## 0.1158 0.9978 0.3430 
> rowMeans(dat, na.rm = TRUE)
##   S01LA   N01AX   N05AG 
## 0.07145 0.17590 0.48095
```

Comment: +1 for the `na.strings` approach. Given the state of the question, I wouldn't bother editing your answer anymore to try to match what they might have in mind :-)

Comment: Haha.  It seems to be turning sour up there at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

```
dat <- read.table(text = 'col1      col2      col3
S01LA   "0.0143"  "0.1286"  "---"                          
N01AX "0.0088"    "---"     "0.343"                         
N05AG "0.0927"    "0.8692"  "---"')
```

First transform the factors to numeric values (you can ignore the warning messages):

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) 
                                 else as.numeric(x))

#         col1   col2  col3
# S01LA 0.0143 0.1286    NA
# N01AX 0.0088     NA 0.343
# N05AG 0.0927 0.8692    NA
```

Second, apply `colsums`

```
colSums(dat, na.rm = TRUE)
#   col1   col2   col3 
# 0.1158 0.9978 0.3430
```

Comment: I think your `else` should be `as.numeric(x)`, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto The `read.table` function automatically converts the first column's values to numeric values. But it's better to use `as.numeric` if the data is represented as strings. I modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Oh. I had misread your intentions. I assumed you were checking whether they were character or factor. Before I had realized that they had a `matrix` not a `data.frame`, I had written an answer pretty much exactly like yours but with `as.numeric`, hence my comment :-)